# ASP.NET Cookies to remember input value in form

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, cookies, webforms

Here is the problem, i have a form in which i need to implement cookies that will remember the input values of specific textboxes so that when for example user enters his Name cookie fills other boxes with remembered values such as his last name, e-mail and phone number.

This is form i need :

[image]

and this is asp.net default.aspx code :

```
        Navn *
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td style="font-weight: bold" valign="top" colspan="3">
                                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtOrdererName" runat="server" ToolTip="Navn" Width="330px" TabIndex="7" OnTextChanged="txtOrdererName_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
                                                                    &nbsp;<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvOrdererName" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtOrdererName"
                                                                            runat="server" ErrorMessage="<img src=Images/validator_requiredInfo.gif class='UCvalidatorSymbol'>" />      
                                                            </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                            <td valign="top">
                                                                    &nbsp;
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td valign="top">
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td valign="top">
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td valign="top">
                                                                    &nbsp;</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                            <td style="font-weight: bold" valign="top">
                                                                    Telefon *
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td style="font-weight: bold" valign="top" colspan="3">
                                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPhone" runat="server" ToolTip="Telefon" Width="330px" TabIndex="8"></asp:TextBox>
                                                                    &nbsp;<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvPhone" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtPhone"
                                                                            runat="server" ErrorMessage="<img src=Images/validator_requiredInfo.gif class='UCvalidatorSymbol'>" />      
                                                            </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                            <td valign="top">
                                                                    &nbsp;
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td style="font-weight: bold; color: red" valign="top" colspan="3">
                                                                    <%--<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revPhone" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPhone"
                                                                            Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Angiv en gyldig telefon (8 digit)" ToolTip="Angiv en gyldig telefon (8 digit)"
                                                                            ValidationExpression="^[0-9]{8}$" />--%>
                                                            </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                            <td style="font-weight: bold" valign="top">
                                                                    Mail *
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td style="font-weight: bold" valign="top" colspan="3">
                                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtOrdererEmail" runat="server" ToolTip="Mail" Width="330px" TabIndex="9"></asp:TextBox>
                                                                    &nbsp;<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvOrdererEmail" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtOrdererEmail"
                                                                            runat="server" ErrorMessage="<img src=Images/validator_requiredInfo.gif class='UCvalidatorSymbol'>" />
                                                            </td>
```

I created some javascript Cookie but i get an error in console for addEventListener and it is :
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null**

This is my javascript :

```
`window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById('btnProceed_Click').addEventListener('click', createCookies);




    // jsfiddle runs code after page loads -- in other environments
    // run this on page load
    document.getElementById("txtOrdererName").value = getCookie("txtOrdererName");
    document.getElementById("txtPhone").value = getCookie("txtPhone");
    document.getElementById("txtOrdererEmail").value = getCookie("txtOrdererEmail");

    // Read values from textboxes and create cookies
    function createCookies(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();

        setCookie('txtOrdererName', document.getElementById("txtOrdererName").value);
        setCookie('txtPhone', document.getElementById("txtPhone").value);
        setCookie('txtOrdererEmail', document.getElementById("txtOrdererEmail").value);
    }

    // set the cookie lifetime
    function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
        var d = new Date();
        exdays = exdays || 365; // Set to 1 year - 365 days
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        var expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
        document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
    }

    function getCookie(cname) {
        var name = cname + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1);
            if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
        return "";
    }
}`
```

Anyone can figure out if this can work and what is the problem ?

Comment: Ok... and why is that a problem? And why Cookies? If you need to store it why not use a Session variable?

Comment: It is problem because this is first time working with cookies, and task is to do it with cookie. If anyone can help I would be very thankful

Comment: Where is the markup for `btnProceed`?  Are you sure it is really called `btnProceed_Click` shouldn't it be just `btnProceed`?

Comment: The error indicates this element `btnProceed_Click` is undefined or null.  I think btnProceed_Click is your click event, the ID of this button is probably btnProceed.  Change your first line of js to this: `document.getElementById('btnProceed').addEventListener('click', createCookies);`

Comment: Oh yes that was mistake, it solved problem that was showing error in console but now I dont get any cookies stored locally... On button clicked it just moves to second page :S I tried with additional button also but when i click on it nothing happens .. I'm really confused now